# How can I print a value in register in decimal?

Tags: assembly, arm

In ARM assembly, how can I print a value in register in decimal? This is the code I have as of now.

```
MOV     r3, #32         ;bit count = 32
MOV     r5,#0; r5 will have the converted decimal number
Loop
MOV     r0, r2, LSR #31   
ADD     r5,r5,r0,LSL r3
MOV     r2, r2, LSL #1           
SUBS    r3, r3, #1                
BNE  Loop
```

My logic has something wrong. Even if I multiply correctly, the resultant value is still hex. What is the way of converting a hex value to its corresponding decimal value?

Comment: This isn't clear.  Please provide an example of input, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: The logic here is a one-bit-at-a-time equivalent of `MOV r5, r2`. Are you trying to get [BCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) or something else? Hint: if a conversion-to-decimal algorithm doesn't contain some sort of division by 10, it's _probably_ wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what your code is trying to do, it makes no sense at all..

Take the number 123 (decimal) and you want to print it out, you need to separate it into the digits 1, 2, 3 and then convert those to ascii then print out the ascii.  converting to ascii for decimal is easy you just add 0x30.

Registers cannot know or care what the bits in them represent 123 decimal in a register is the same bit pattern as 0x7B in the register, the register and logic cannot know the difference.  same goes for 0173 octal...

Now how did our brains take 123 and turn it into 1, 2, 3?  Well it is easy if you are in the right base, but still it is a process of division and remainders.  You start by taking 123 dividing by the base, 10, and getting 12 remainder 3.  that remainder gets us our least significant digit. and we can repeat that until our result is 0 because after that point we will always get 0 remainder 0.  So 12 / 10  = 1 remainder 2 giving our next digit, then lastly 1/10 = 0 remainder 1 and we are done 3, 2, 1 in reverse order are the digits.

Now ARM's generally dont have a divide instruction, since the alu is base 2 you cant just shift and mask, you have to divide by 10.  there are many ways to do this.   so it certainly doesnt have a divide function with a remainder in one step so you will have to find the remainder with an extra step  123 / 10 = 12,  then 12+10 = 120,  123 - 120 = 3, that gets 12 remainder 3.  repeat.

The simplest way to implement but by far the least efficient is subtraction.  start with 123 and have a loop that subtracts 10 until the number is less than 10,  0) 123, 1) 113, 2) 103, 3) 93, 4) 83, 5) 73, 6) 63, 7) 53, 8) 43, 9) 33, 10) 23, 11) 13, 12) 3   12 remainder 3.

This will give you the remainders in reverse order, so you have to deal with that, and remember to add 0x30 to each one to make it ascii.

Naturally if you want to discover them in forward order and be a little less efficient (depends on your divide).  123/100 = 1, 123-100 = 23, 23/10 = 2, 2*10 = 20, 23-20 = 3 and that is less than 10 done. 1, 2, 3 in forward order but you have to guesstimate how many digits to deal with or go with worst case all the time rather than having an early out.

All of this has been well covered many times at stackoverflow, likewise the how do I divide by 10 problem has also been beaten to death.  Do some more searching please.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I was able to implement the method in which you divide repeatedly to get the reminders and was able to print in the reverse order. But as ARM assembly doesnot have a DIV instructon, I did repeated subtraction to achieve this. So the program is very very slow for large numbers(like 0xFFFFFFFF). Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: get the hackers delight, or read http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~jones/bcd/divide.html or search stackoverflow or google as converting to decimal and how to divide by 10 have been covered many times.  or just take the division code from the gcc library (in the gcc sources)